# Python Dictonary KeyError when key exist

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python, and I'm doing a homework with it.

I'm using PyEDA with Python3 on Debian 8.

I created a variable named:

```
R = exprvars('r', n, n)
```

with `n = 4`, this gives me:

```
farray([[r[0,0], r[0,1], r[0,2], r[0,3]],
    [r[1,0], r[1,1], r[1,2], r[1,3]],
    [r[2,0], r[2,1], r[2,2], r[2,3]],
    [r[3,0], r[3,1], r[3,2], r[3,3]]])
```

Then, after some logic, I create an CNF boolean function f and a BDD with it using:

```
f = expr2bdd(f)
```

Then, the expression:

```
U = f.satisfy_one()
```

gives me:

```
{r[2,1]: 0, r[3,2]: 1, r[1,1]: 1, r[0,2]: 0, r[0,3]: 1, r[2,2]: 0, r[2,3]: 0, r[3,3]: 0, r[3,1]: 0, r[1,2]: 0, r[0,1]: 0, r[1,0]: 0, r[2,0]: 1, r[3,0]: 0, r[0,0]: 0, r[1,3]: 0}
```

But here is what I can't understand:
I was expecting

```
U[R[0,0]]
```

To return a 0, but instead it gives me

```
KeyError: r[0,0]
```

What is the problem? `R[0,0]` gives me `r[0,0]` and the dictionary do have it as a key.

[edit]

When I said `R[0,0]` gives me `r[0,0]`, this means that I printed it using pdb, placing a breakpoint right after `U = f.satisfy_one()`:

```
(Pdb) p R[0,0]
r[0,0]
```

Comment: You have to share the codes for `exprvars() expr2bdd() satisfy_one()` We can not help you without knowing what these functions do.

Comment: those are functions provided by PyEDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs more details.

How do you say, `R[0,0]` gives me `r[0,0]`? Did you print them?

Try to verify if you are looking for same

```
assert list(U.keys())[0] == R[2,1]
```

Look the the values

```
print(list(type(U.keys())[0])
print(type(R[2,1])
```

See if they match, only if they match, will you be able to gather it.

Also, check if `U` itself has any methods to do the query for you.

Comment: I Used the pdb to check that R[0,0] gives r[0,0]

Comment: I Just pasted your commands in pdb, I placed a breakpoint after U = f.satisfy_one():

    (Pdb) assert U.keys()[0] == R[2,1]

    *** TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
    (Pdb) print(type(U.keys()[0]))

    *** TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
    (Pdb) print(type(R[2,1]))

    <class 'pyeda.boolalg.expr.Variable'>

Comment: Try list(U.keys()][0] for the above.

Comment: list(U.keys())[0] returns me r[1,3], then
U[list(U.keys())[0]] returns me 0

Comment: Well, the types really don't match. I think this is the answer to my problem :

(Pdb) p type(list(U.keys())[0])
<class 'pyeda.boolalg.bdd.BDDVariable'>
(Pdb) p type(R[2,1])
<class 'pyeda.boolalg.expr.Variable'>